# Create new columns and calculate values based on condition with date in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pandas.excelwriter

I need to create a new column as Billing and Non-Billing based on the Date column.

Condition for Column 1 : If the Start Date is `NULL` OR `BLANK` (OR) if its Start Date is  in 'Future Date' (OR) if its Starts Date is in 'Past Date' (OR) if its End Date is in Past Date then I should create a new column as Non-Billing.

Condition for columns 2: If the Start Date is in 'Current Date' then need to create a new column as 'Billable' and need to calculate it. Calculation should be in row axis.

Calculation for Billing in row: `Billing = df[Billing] * sum/168 * 100`

Calculation for Non-Billing in row: `Non-Billing = df[Non-Billing] * sum/ 168 * 100`

**Data:**

```
Employee Name  |    Java  |  Python  | .NET  |  React  |  Start Date   |  End Date    |                                

|Anu           |    10    |     10   |   5   |     5   |  04-21-2021   |              |                                 
|Kalai         |          |     10   |       |     5   |  04-21-2021   |  10-31-2021  |                                 
|Smirthi       |          |     10   |   20  |         |  03-21-2021   |              |                               
|Madhu         |    20    |     10   |   10  |         |  01-12-2021   |              |
|Latha         |    40    |          |   5   |         |               |              |
```

**Input**

[image: Input]

**Output**

[image: Output]

**Code:**

```
# Adding new columns 
total=df.sum(axis=1) 
df.insert(len(df.columns),column='Total',value=total) 
    
# Adding Utilization column utilization = (total/168) 
df.insert(len(df.columns), column='Utilization', value=utilization) 
    
# Filter dataframe using groupby 
df1 = df.groupby(['Employee Name']).sum(min_count=1) 
df1['Available'] = 168
```

Comment: please show the code you have tried

Comment: @Jayvee 
'code'
# Adding new columns 
total=df.sum(axis=1)
df.insert(len(df.columns),column='Total',value=total)

# Adding Utilization column
utilization = (total/168)
df.insert(len(df.columns), column='Utilization', value=utilization)

# Filter dataframe using groupby
df1 = df.groupby(['Employee Name']).sum(min_count=1)
df1['Available'] = 168

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the conditions very well as there seem to be some inconsistencies but I believe this will help you getting started:

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
import datetime

df['Total'] = df.sum(axis=1)
df['Available']=168
df['Amount']=df['Total']/df['Available']*100
df['Billing']=np.NaN
df['NonBilling']=np.NaN
df.loc[df['Start Date']==datetime.date.today(),'Billing']= df['Amount']
df.loc[df['Start Date']!=datetime.date.today(),'NonBilling']= df['Amount']
```

NOTES:

1. make sure about the date type to compare against today's date, if your date are being loaded as objects you may want to do something like this after loading:

   df['Start Date']= pd.to_datetime(df['Start Date']).dt.date
2. work out the conditions for Billing/NonBilling to make sure the columns are being populated as intended

Comment: happy to help, please accept the answer if you are happy with it, thank you